# Sum of a function Θ(g) with a function that is not O(g)

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

Consider g a function of n: $g(n)$.

Knowing that the function $f(n) \in Θ(g(n))$ and the function $h(n) \notin O(g(n))$, could we conclude anything, related to it's asymptotic behaviour, about $f(n) + h(n)$ with respect to $g(n)$?

Given that $f(n)$ is $Θ(g(n))$, I have that $f(n)$ grows *the same way as* $g(n)$.
Given that $h(n)$ is not $O(g(n))$, I have that $h(n)$ grows *more rapidly* compared to $g(n)$.

In my mind, at least, it seems like these two above observations are sufficient to conclude that $f(n) + h(n)$ grows (just like $h(n)$) more rapidly than $g(n)$ and, thus, $ f(n) + h(n) \in O(g(n))$, but I'm afraid it's a counterintuitive case or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f\in \Theta(g)$ and $h\notin \mathcal{O}(g)$. That means:
$$\exists A>0, B>0, \forall n\geqslant 0, Ag(n) \leqslant f(n) \leqslant Bg(n)$$
and
$$\forall C>0, \exists n\geqslant 0, h(n) > Cg(n)$$

Therefore, for all $C>0$, there exists $n\geqslant 0$ such that $h(n) > (C-A)g(n)$. We conclude that $f(n) + h(n) > Ag(n) + (C-A)g(n) = Cg(n)$.

We just proved that $f +h\notin\mathcal{O}(g)$.

Note that I supposed here that all functions are positive.